# "Deletes are not allowed as it will invalidate the Meta Vaut AuditLog" SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

```
use DatabaseExample
go

DELETE FROM schema1.table1;
DELETE FROM schema2.table2;
DELETE FROM schema3.table3;

EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

I have changed the names of the tables/databases as I do not want to risk sharing sensitive information. However Whenever I attempt to delete a table from SCHEMA2, it gives me the following message :

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tdel_Batches, Line 21
>   Deletes are not allowed as it will invalidate the Meta Vault AuditLog. You can disable the trigger at your own risk.
>
> Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

I tried disabling the triggers for the entire server but that had no affect. Like i said it is only tables in a specific schema, the others are fine. The two stored procedures are to disable any key constraints and then re enable them after I am done.

Comment: what do you mean with *tried disabling the triggers....but had no effect*?, what did you actually do and what exactly happened

Comment: "DISABLE Trigger all on all server;
go"

and i kept getting the same exact error messages

Comment: how did you disabled them?, did you went table by table disabling the triggers?

Comment: no, i just showed you the code i used, At the top i did DISABLE Trigger ALL ON ALL SERVER

Comment: Well, you should try disabling the trigger directly on the table

Comment: the only problem is that there is like 25 tables in this schema

Comment: But you need to disable the trigger associated with the table that you want to delete data from

Comment: I know, but i want to delete the data from all of the tables.

Comment: then maybe try `sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? DISABLE TRIGGER all'`

Comment: yup that seemed to work...thanks...if you want to put it as an answer i will accept it

Comment: Of course in no way should you ever do this unless you know exactly why that trigger was there and what it does. It may have been put there specifically to prevent people like you from deleting data from those tables. That data my be owned by someone who will be very upset that you deleted it.

Comment: yea thats something i considered, but its a backup copy of a demo DB, but I will definitely look more into the reasoning behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be in the triggers, so you should try disabling them in the tables that you want to delete data from:

```
sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? DISABLE TRIGGER all';
```

If you want to enable them again afterwards, then you can do;

```
sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? ENABLE TRIGGER all';
```